# C++ convert std::string to byte array

Tags: javascript, c++, arduino, bluetooth-lowenergy, std

Bear with me as I'm new to C++, pointers, etc..

I'm sending over raw image data to a microcontroller using `Arduino` via `BLE`.

Currently, I'm using `JS` to send the raw data over as an `ArrayBuffer`. However (surprisingly), it looks like I can only receive the data on the Arduino side as a `String` and not raw Bytes.

I verified this by looking at the param the `onWrite` cb takes. It takes a `BLECharacteristic` Object. Doc here [BLECharacteristic](http://www.neilkolban.com/esp32/docs/cpp_utils/html/class_b_l_e_characteristic.html) doesn't show any instance methods or anything to receive data...just the `getValue` fn which returns a String. Printing this String out on Serial shows weird symbols..guessing just something similar to `ArrayBuffer.toString()`...?

I'd then like to convert this `String` data to a `Byte` array so that I can display it on an epaper display.

Here is my BLE `onWrite` cb.

```
class MyCallbacks: public BLECharacteristicCallbacks {
void onWrite(BLECharacteristic *pCharacteristic) {
    std::string value = pCharacteristic->getValue();

    int n = value.length();

    char const *cstr = new char [value.length()+1];
    std::strcpy (cstr, value.c_str());

    display.drawBitmap(0,0,*c,296,128,EPD_BLACK);
  }
}};
```

This doesn't work and I get `invalid conversion from 'const char*' to 'char*'`

Note: The format the `drawBitmap` function is expecting is `const uint8_t` (byte array).
[drawBitmap docs](http://adafruit.github.io/Adafruit-GFX-Library/html/class_adafruit___g_f_x.html#a805a15f1b3ea9eff5d1666b8e6db1c56)

However, I've gotten this to work by using a hardcoded array in the format of

```
const unsigned char foo [] = {
    0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff
};
```

So I'm confused on the difference between `const char []`, `const uint8_t`, and `byte array`. May someone please explain the differences? Then - how can I convert my String of raw data into that the `drawBitmap` fn is expecting?

Comment: `char const *cstr` is a pointer to the new array which you can't use to write to it, it is presumed to point to a `const` array of `char`. You need `char *cstr`.

Comment: Also note that you can use `value.c_str()` or `value.data()` directly.

Comment: One more reason to just use `value.c_str()`: `char const *cstr = new char [value.length()+1];` was leaked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems to be quite simple, std::strcpy() needs a pointer to writable (not const) memory, therefor the pointer cstr may not point to const char, leave out const and the following should work:

```
char *cstr = new char [value.length()+1];
std::strcpy (cstr, value.c_str());
```

If you feel fancy, I believe you could use a const pointer to char, meaning the content can be changed but not the pointer itself, this however seems unnecessary:

```
char * const cstr = new char [value.length()+1];
std::strcpy (cstr, value.c_str());
```

Comment: Hi!

This solves my first error, but now I get `no matching function for call to 'drawBitmap(int, int, char&, int, int, <unnamed enum>)'`

http://adafruit.github.io/Adafruit-GFX-Library/html/class_adafruit___g_f_x.html#a805a15f1b3ea9eff5d1666b8e6db1c56 

shows that the fn expects `const uint8_t  bitmap[]` type.

and something in format of 
`const unsigned char foo [] = {
    0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff
};`
does work.

How can I convert what you have above into something the fn will take? Thanks!

Comment: The only problem seems to be that you just need cstr to be unsigned:

`unsigned char *cstr = new char [value.length()+1];
std::strcpy (cstr, value.c_str());`

Comment: The above comment might cause problems with `strcpy()`, if that is the case I would cast in the `drawBitmap()` call: `display.drawBitmap(0,0,(unsinged char *)cstr,296,128,EPD_BLACK);`

Comment: The casting part worked. Ty!